# Reference for the triple covering of A_6

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I would like to ask for a reference (book, paper ...) for the following nice construction, which I have found as an exercise in some notes of a course by R. Borcherds. For $n=6$ or $7$ (and only in that case), the alternating group $\mathfrak{A}_n$ has a nontrivial central extension by $\mathbb{Z}/3$. The construction in the case $n=6$ is as follows.

Define an *oval* in  $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{F}_4)$ as a set of 6 points which are in general position (i.e. no 3 of them are collinear). It is easy to show that any projective frame of $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{F}_4)$ is contained in a unique oval, and from this that the stabilizer of an oval in $PGL_3(\mathbb{F}_4)$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{A}_6$. The inverse image of this $\mathfrak{A}_6$ in $SL_3(\mathbb{F}_4)$ provides the nontrivial extension by $\mathbb{Z}/3$.

Does anyone know a reference for this? and/or an analogous construction for $\mathfrak{A}_7$?

Comment: Any luck with the references from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentiner_group ?  I could only find a brief mention on page 23 of the ATLAS.

Comment: No, all I have seen works over $\mathbb{C}$, with explicit (and complicated) matrices. The Wikipedia article itself mentions the construction, perhaps this is an acceptable reference, thanks!

Comment: The Wikipedia article is not really independent of the course notes, as far as human sources are concerned - see the edit history.

Comment: Not really perfect as it gives a different construction (as a subgroup of $GL(6,\mathbb{C})$), but quite interesting in any case - thanks to you and to Leandro.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The oval construction for $3\cdot A_6$ can be found on p.110 of

> *Symmetric Generation of Groups With Applications to Many of the Sporadic Finite
>   Simple Groups* by Robert Curtis.

An e-version is [here](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MA_Algebra/MAtg_Group%20theory/Curtis%20R.T.%20Symmetric%20generation%20of%20groups%20%28CUP,%202007%29%28ISBN%20052185721X%29%28O%29%28331s%29_MAtg_.pdf). In fact Curtis does better: he constructs $3\cdot A_6\cdot 2^2$.

If you read on to p.112 and beyond you will also find a construction of $3\cdot A_7$, as you requested.

(It seems like the e-version is freely available on the web. But if you can't get it, contact me and I'll email it to you.)

Comment: Hi Nick, It looks like the page is taken down. Could you send it to me at upaudel92@gmail.com ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

It is not exactly what you are looking for, but it might be useful.

You can find an interesting construction of the triple covering for the alternating group $\mathbb{A}_6$ in Chapter 2, Section 7.3 of Wilson's book:

Wilson, Robert A. The finite simple groups. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 251. Springer-Verlag London, Ltd., London, 2009. xvi+298 pp. ISBN: 978-1-84800-987-5 MR2562037 (2011e:20018)

[Here](http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=lYMAg_Sj7hUC&lpg=PR9&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false) you have the link (Google books).